# SQL Server cannot process this media family

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I am trying to restore one backup file but I am not able to do it.

I get this error:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   The media family on device 'D:\Case_info\NEWPMS_db_201606261000.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

Comment: did you tried to search for this common error..http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/media-family-on-device-is-incorrectly-formed-sql-server-cannot-process-this-med

Comment: Really more of a DBA (rather than **programming**) question -> should be on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: does it come from a newer version of sql server than your current?